# Oracle Cloud - Why can I use sudo without a password?

Tags: sudo, password

I have a new user account created on an oracle cloud free tier VM, called `testacc`. This account is a member of the `sudo` group, and the `testacc` group. Password login is disabled, and I log in with a public key authentication.

If the account has a password, then when using sudo I need to enter the password. If the account does not have a password from using `sudo passwd -d testacc`, then I do not need to enter the password for sudo.

Running `sudo visudo` clearly shows that `NOPASSWD:ALL` is not there for the `sudo` group. Checking `/etc/sudoers.d` shows an entry that has `NOPASSWD:ALL`, but it's only for the `ubuntu` group.

I don't understand why I don't have to enter the password. This is absolutely the functionality I want - where if I'm using SSH to log in and don't have a user password set then I don't need to use a password for sudo, but if I do have a password configured then I do - but I've got no idea where this is actually configured.

Everything I read relates it to `NOPASSWD:ALL`, but this VM definitely does not have that applicable to this user. In addition, when using another VM I have, unsetting the password with `sudo passwd -d` results in me being unable to use sudo due to it asking for a password that doesn't exist

---

How does this work exactly, and how can I set my system up so that if a user has a password they need to enter it for `sudo`, but if they don't then it doesn't ask for one?

Thanks

---

Output of sudo -l

```
Matching Defaults entries for testacc on oracle:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User testacc may run the following commands on oracle:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Output of `/etc/pam.d/sudo`

```
#%PAM-1.0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

Output of sudo -V as root

```
Sudo version 1.8.31
Configure options: --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking -v --with-all-insults --with-pam --with-fqdn --with-logging=syslog --with-logfac=authpriv --with-env-editor --with-editor=/usr/bin/editor --with-exampledir=/usr/share/doc/sudo/examples --with-timeout=15 --with-password-timeout=0 --with-passprompt=[sudo] password for %p:  --without-lecture --with-tty-tickets --disable-root-mailer --enable-admin-flag --with-sendmail=/usr/sbin/sendmail --with-rundir=/run/sudo --libexecdir=/usr/lib --with-sssd --with-sssd-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-selinux --with-linux-audit --enable-tmpfiles.d=yes
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.31
Sudoers file grammar version 46

Sudoers path: /etc/sudoers
Authentication methods: 'pam'
Syslog facility if syslog is being used for logging: authpriv
Syslog priority to use when user authenticates successfully: notice
Syslog priority to use when user authenticates unsuccessfully: alert
Send mail if user authentication fails
Send mail if the user is not in sudoers
Lecture user the first time they run sudo
Require users to authenticate by default
Root may run sudo
Allow some information gathering to give useful error messages
Require fully-qualified hostnames in the sudoers file
Visudo will honor the EDITOR environment variable
Set the LOGNAME and USER environment variables
Length at which to wrap log file lines (0 for no wrap): 80
Authentication timestamp timeout: 15.0 minutes
Password prompt timeout: 0.0 minutes
Number of tries to enter a password: 3
Umask to use or 0777 to use user's: 022
Path to mail program: /usr/sbin/sendmail
Flags for mail program: -t
Address to send mail to: root
Subject line for mail messages: *** SECURITY information for %h ***
Incorrect password message: Sorry, try again.
Path to lecture status dir: /var/lib/sudo/lectured
Path to authentication timestamp dir: /run/sudo/ts
Default password prompt: [sudo] password for %p:
Default user to run commands as: root
Value to override user's $PATH with: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
Path to the editor for use by visudo: /usr/bin/editor
When to require a password for 'list' pseudocommand: any
When to require a password for 'verify' pseudocommand: all
File descriptors >= 3 will be closed before executing a command
Reset the environment to a default set of variables
Environment variables to check for sanity:
        TZ
        TERM
        LINGUAS
        LC_*
        LANGUAGE
        LANG
        COLORTERM
Environment variables to remove:
        *=()*
        RUBYOPT
        RUBYLIB
        PYTHONUSERBASE
        PYTHONINSPECT
        PYTHONPATH
        PYTHONHOME
        TMPPREFIX
        ZDOTDIR
        READNULLCMD
        NULLCMD
        FPATH
        PERL5DB
        PERL5OPT
        PERL5LIB
        PERLLIB
        PERLIO_DEBUG
        JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
        SHELLOPTS
        BASHOPTS
        GLOBIGNORE
        PS4
        BASH_ENV
        ENV
        TERMCAP
        TERMPATH
        TERMINFO_DIRS
        TERMINFO
        _RLD*
        LD_*
        PATH_LOCALE
        NLSPATH
        HOSTALIASES
        RES_OPTIONS
        LOCALDOMAIN
        CDPATH
        IFS
Environment variables to preserve:
        XAUTHORIZATION
        XAUTHORITY
        PS2
        PS1
        PATH
        LS_COLORS
        KRB5CCNAME
        HOSTNAME
        DPKG_COLORS
        DISPLAY
        COLORS
Locale to use while parsing sudoers: C
Directory in which to store input/output logs: /var/log/sudo-io
File in which to store the input/output log: %{seq}
Add an entry to the utmp/utmpx file when allocating a pty
PAM service name to use: sudo
PAM service name to use for login shells: sudo
Attempt to establish PAM credentials for the target user
Create a new PAM session for the command to run in
Perform PAM account validation management
Maximum I/O log sequence number: 0
Enable sudoers netgroup support
Check parent directories for writability when editing files with sudoedit
Allow commands to be run even if sudo cannot write to the audit log
Allow commands to be run even if sudo cannot write to the log file
Log entries larger than this value will be split into multiple syslog messages: 960
File mode to use for the I/O log files: 0600
Execute commands by file descriptor instead of by path: digest_only
Type of authentication timestamp record: tty
Ignore case when matching user names
Ignore case when matching group names
Log when a command is allowed by sudoers
Log when a command is denied by sudoers

Local IP address and netmask pairs:
        10.0.0.87/255.255.255.0
        fe80::17ff:fe02:9bba/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::

Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.31
```

Comment: Is this using Ubuntu? What is the output of `sudo -l` ad the `testacc` user, and `sudo -V` as the root user? What does `/etc/pam.d/sudo` contain?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll edit the responses into the main post. Added sudo -l and the contents of pam, I'm assuming it's probably one of those additional two lines that does it but I've no idea how.

Comment: `Perform PAM account validation management` feels like the culprit, but I've no idea how that gets set. I'm a novice with PAM etc.

Comment: The only PAM module I'm aware of that does something like this is [pam_ssh_agent_auth](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/pam_ssh_agent_auth.8.html) - but that does not seem to be in play here. Did you ensure that your credentials were not still cached from the `sudo passwd -d` command (using `sudo -k` for example)?

Comment: Just tried that and it still authenticated without the password.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users
```

And you can see :

```
# Created by cloud-init v. (...)

# User rules for ubuntu
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: Thank you, it's been a while and I can't remember exactly, but doesn't this only cover the `ubuntu` group? This was happening with accounts that weren't in the ubuntu group.

Comment: you are right.   i got it wrong...